# No other language than English can be typed or displayed in terminal

Tags: terminal, fonts, arch-linux, language, locale

I am not sure whether it has something to do with my locale settings, which are hopefully fine, or fonts.

```
 locale -a
C
en_US.utf8
POSIX
ru_RU.utf8
uk_UA.utf8
```

When I switch between keyboard layouts I can type, say in libreoffice or firefox on any language, i.e. ua,ru,en.
However, when I type in the terminal, if the language is ru or ua, not one symbol is typed in, nothing is typed in.
Again, if I `ls` files in directory, ua and ru letters are not displayed, en are. Unicode is also not displayed.
Fonts issue?

I use Arch with Suckless Terminal, however this issue applies to `dmenu` and to xterm too.

Comment: When you type and nothing is displayed, does the cursor move? If you type a command "blind" and press enter does the display scroll with (invisible) output? Please edit your question to add that information. Remember we can't see your screen, provide as much information as possible on what you observe.

Comment: Sounds like a codepage set to the wrong value. Find out what the codepage for russian is, then use `chcp 866` to change the codepage to russian. Default is 850 Latin, which does not support russian characters. (https://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html) 65001 might also work btw.

Comment: Tonny, no, cursor doesn't move. Nothing happens as I type, as if I was not typing at all.
LPChip, I use Linux/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Locale#Setting_the_system_locale

It just happens that I had not configured system locale.
I checked the output of `locale` command - `LANG='C'`, then, according to the wiki:

> localectl set-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8

logged out and logged in (restarted the session)

Read the wiki for more detail.